# Can I deploy solutions to Azure Marketplace that are AKS based?

Tags: azure-marketplace

Is it possible to publish a solution in Azure Marketplace that is on top of AKS (instead of VMs)?

Answer (score 0):

No, aks is not yet supported with Marketplace

Comment: Is this still the case?